# Codeigniter : Access session from config

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, config

I am making an application using Codeigniter which requires URL changes before login and after login
I want all the URLs before login with `http://` and after login my `base_url` should be with `https://`.

So basically, what I want to access the session in config and then by using the session variable I can able to change the `base_url` format.

so please help me out to access the session with config file OR any alternative of this.

Comment: it is because the site is having such assurance that after login you will have all the things secure. and based on other functionality, It needs to be done.

Comment: I agree with @Repox, but if you really want to, why don't you just write a my_base_url function that takes the string returned by base_url, checks if user is logged in and in that case changes http to https

Comment: @danneth - Yes, I totally agree with your answer, But the problem is whole site is already built now. and It will be to hard and risky to change all the files.

Comment: I did not know this, but if you look at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html you can actually extend/overload helpers as well, perhaps it would be possible to solve that way

Comment: Okay danneth. Then will you please suggest me where should I write this function, so that It will be called up initially on load of application and What if I would like to override the base_url function?

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```